# I am struggling to pass data to controller through Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api2

Trying to hit `DeleteJobQuote` controller  through Ajax but no luck. Please guide me if anyone has any idea about it. The code seems OK but not able to do so. I am writing this code to delete a particular record from database.

**Controller**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteJobQuote(int jobQuoteid)
{
    using (var db = new KeysEntities())
    {
        var delJob = db.JobQuote.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == jobQuoteid);
        if (delJob != null)
        {
            delJob.Status = "Delete";
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { success = true, Message = "JobQuote SuccessFully Deleted!" });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, Message = "Delete UnSuccessFul " });
        }
    }
}
```

**And JavaScript and Knockout code for this**

```js
self.deleteJobQuote = function (jobQuote) {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Companies/Manage/DeleteJobQuote',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ko.toJSON(this),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                $('#jobQuoteDeleteModal').modal('show');
            }
            else {
                alert("You can not delete this record !!");
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly? I cant see any line that performs delete operation like `db.JobQuote.Remove(delJob );` in your code.

Comment: What is `this` on line `data: ko.toJSON(this)` ? What's the error ?

Comment: @S.Akbari,  From Ajax, i am unable to hit controller to see the result. From this line  $.ajax({, it is not going inside.

Comment: Have you tried to use `JSON.Stringify`? Something like this `data: JSON.Stringify({jobQuoteid: jobQuoteidValue})`?

Comment: @Max, I have changed from data: { id: data.Id() } to ko.toJSON(this) to see the effect but no luck so far.

Comment: @S.Akbari, No i did not try JSON.Stringify. I will try it now and will see. Thanks

Comment: In Controller use `ActionResult` replace to `JsonResult`

Comment: @S.Akbari, I tried JSON.Stringify(jobQuote), but it is throwing error " JSON.Stringify is not a function".

Comment: See my previous comment to know how to use it: `data: JSON.Stringify({jobQuoteid: jobQuoteidValue})`

Comment: @S.Akbari, i tried putting data: JSON.Stringify({ jobQuoteid: 1028 }), but no luck. The error is same JSON.Stringify is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "data : ko.toJSON(this)" to "data: JSON.stringify({ jobQuoteid: 1 })". I have hardcoded jobQuoteid value to 1. Get it from jobQoute object.

complete code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/Companies/Manage/DeleteJobQuote',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ jobQuoteid: 1 }),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#jobQuoteDeleteModal').modal('show');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("You can not delete this record !!");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: If JSON.stringify doesn't work. Try to use json data directly.

data: '{ "jobQuoteid" : 1}'